# Is it possible using regular expression in inbox rule criteria

Tags: microsoft-outlook, regex, exchange, inbox, email-filter

I want to filter all mail whose subject starts with **[SomeWord]**, so I wonder is it possible using regular expression(such as **^\[SomeWord\]**) for inbox rule of outlook.

I'm using outlook web aceess, not outlook client.

Comment: "^[SomeWord]" is not the regular expression you are looking for </jedimindtrick>

Comment: @jae, thanks for pointing out the wrong usage of sample regular expression. Not sure what "jedimindtrick" means, will google it. :)

Comment: it's a Star Wars reference http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JediMindTrick

Comment: There is [a Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865500/regular-expression-rules-in-outlook-2007) which has some solutions for doing this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry but currently Outlook rules (up to Outlook 2016) don't support regular expressions.

The current way rules work, are that they can look for **[SomeWord]** in any place in the subject, but you can't force it so that it only happens as the first word.